# Removing duplicate entries in an array- Undefined offset error(PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, undefined, offset

I am new to PHP and am trying to remove duplicate entries in an array.  I end up with my desired output, but I am also getting two "Undefined offset" errors along the way. This is the code I have:
$this->master refers to an array declared in the beginning of the class.

```
    public function removeDuplicates(){
        $var = count($this->master);
            for($i = 0; $i < $var; $i++){
                    for($j = 0; $j <$var; $j++){
                        if(($this->master[$i] == $this->master[$j]) && $i != $j){                           
                            $this->shiftLeft($j, $var);
                            $var --;
                        }
                    }
            }
    }

    public function shiftLeft($t, $s){
        while($t < $s){
            echo "$t ";
            $this->master[$t] = $this->master[$t+1];
            $t++;
        }
        unset($this->master[$t-1]);
    }
```

It is probably a really simple logical error but I cannot seem to find where.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use array_unique? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if it works

```
 $unique = array_unique($this->master);
```

Comment: That gives me an array of the duplicate entries, without any of the non-duplicates.  How can I have if give me an array of only one instance of the duplicates?  So if the array was (a,b,a,c) the new array would be (a,b,c)? @andreas

Comment: Are you sure that is what it's doing? It's supposed to give you the array without dupes, not the dupes.